# ODP.NET bulk copy

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert, odp.net

I have a question on Oracle's ODP.NET BulkCopy method.
Does anyone have any ideea how this method is implemented ?
I want to know if it uses array binding...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consult the documentation:

> The ODP.NET Bulk Copy feature uses a
>   direct path load approach, which is
>   similar to, but not the same as Oracle
>   SQL*Loader. Using direct path load is
>   faster than conventional loading
>   (using conventional SQL INSERT
>   statements). Conventional loading
>   formats Oracle data blocks and writes
>   the data blocks directly to the data
>   files. Bulk Copy eliminates
>   considerable processing overhead.

For more, see the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/featADO20.htm#sthref262).